# How to change Firebase topic for some users in specified time?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have an Android education app and we use FCM Topic Messaging for sending specific notifications to each user. We categorized each user according to academic year.

Now, we have one problem for topic messaging, in the specified time, these students goes to one level higher and if we don't change the topic in Firebase for new academic year, it gives the last year notification.

How can we do this? Does Firebase have a solution for this problem? Thanks <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done through your App Server by using the [InstanceID API](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#create_relationship_maps_for_app_instances).

You can `batchAdd` the corresponding tokens to the new topic (i.e. academicy year) you need, then `batchRemove` them from the old topic (i.e. last year).

From the link above:

> **Manage relationship maps for multiple app instances**
>
> Using the Instance ID service's batch methods, you can perform batch management of app instances. For example, you can perform bulk addition or removal of app instances to an FCM or GCM topic. To manage app instances, call the Instance ID service at this endpoint, providing the app instance tokens in the JSON body:
>
> ```
> https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchAdd
>
> https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchRemove
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> - `Authorization`: key=YOUR_API_KEY. Set this parameter in the header.
> - `to` : The topic name.
> - `registration_tokens` : The array of IID tokens for the app instances you want to add or remove.
>
> Results
>
> On success the call returns HTTP status 200. Empty results indicate successful subscription for the token. For failed subscriptions, the result contains one of these error codes:
>
> - NOT_FOUND — The registration token has been deleted or the app has been uninstalled.
> - INVALID_ARGUMENT — The registration token provided is not valid for the Sender ID.
> - INTERNAL — The backend server failed for unknown reasons. Retry the request.
> - TOO_MANY_TOPICS — Excessive number of topics per app instance.
>
> Example POST request
>
> ```
> https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchAdd
> Content-Type:application/json
> Authorization:key=API_KEY
> {
>    "to": "/topics/movies",
>    "registration_tokens": ["nKctODamlM4:CKrh_PC8kIb7O...", "1uoasi24:9jsjwuw...", "798aywu:cba420..."],
> }
> ```
>
> Example result
>
> ```
> HTTP 200 OK
> {
>   "results":[
>     {},
>     {"error":"NOT_FOUND"},
>     {},
>   ]
> }
> ```